# Simple injector - accessing injected instance from background thread

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am using SimpleInjector within an app I'm working on, where I have something similar to the following:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly Bar _bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)            
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
    
    public void DoSomething()
    {                        
        IEnumerable<Order> orders = _bar.Orders;            
    }
}
```

The behaviour I have is that `Foo.DoSomething` is called from a background thread (Task.Run) and `Bar` is registered in the Main method of the app (Windows form app) with a singleton lifestyle. The concern I have is if the implementation of `Bar` supplied to `Foo` is not thread safe.

The main issue I have is that `Bar` has state that is needed by `Foo`, and this state is set before by the main thread before `Foo.DoSomething` is called. I've looked around for solutions to this situation I'm facing, however I wasn't able to find one that helped (unless I'm just going the wrong way about this).

I've looked at the suggestion on [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#decoration) page, which uses a decorator when an instance is executed on background threads. However that didn't help because the state of `Bar` is set on a different thread (Main thread), and using the decorator will just create a new instance of `Bar` with no state.

So I guess my question is am I going to just have to register Bar as a singleton and make sure the registered implementation is thread safe, or is there an obvious solution to this problem that is staring me right in the face but I can't seem to see?

Hope the info I provided is sufficient. Let me know please if you need any further info.

Thanks

**Update**
`Bar` is simply a class that holds lists of info the app needs throughout. For example:

```
public class Bar: IBar
{
    // Not using orders or products, but just for purpose of the example
    // These are initialized early on in the App process because early
    // steps of the app (which are on the main thread) need them.
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
```

The following is the form app where I use Foo:

```
public partial class App: Form
{        
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    public App(IFoo foo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _foo = foo;            
    }

    public btn1_Click()
    {
        // This is just for the purpose of showing that the data inside Bar 
        // is loaded on the main thread before Foo.DoSomething is run. In 
        // the real app the Bar data is loaded at previous steps of the app 
        // (the app is a wizard like app).
        LoadBarData();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _foo.DoSomething();
        });

        // The issue would be if for example Bar is changed here while the 
        // background thread is running. In my app it doesn't really change 
        // here, but I want to make sure no issues arise in all scenarios, 
        // whether it changes or not.            
    }
}
```

And finally here is my Main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    using (Container container = new Container())
    {
        container.Register<IBar, Bar>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<App>();
    }
    Application.Run(container.GetInstance<App>());
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code for Bar and Main.

Comment: @Steven I've edited the question to include more info. Hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Bar is registered in the Main method of the app (Windows form app) with a singleton lifestyle. The concern I have is if the implementation of Bar supplied to Foo is not thread safe.

In case your application runs operations in parallel that access `Bar`, you better make sure `Bar` -and the values it returns- are thread-safe.

This shouldn't be a problem if `Bar` and its values are *immutable* and are set just once during application startup. If `Bar` or its values are mutable, things can start to get more difficult rapidly, but this all depends on your application's needs.

There are a [few general rules](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications) that you should follow to prevent common pitfals, such as:

- Singletons should be thread-safe.
- Do not start background-threads from application code: move this to the Composition Root.

The first point we talked about. The second point is something that is going wrong in your case as well, since you call `Task.Run` from within your button click. In general, application code should not be concerned about whether or not operations run in parallel or not. They should only use a given abstraction (`IFoo` in this case) for what it is. This means that `App` should only call `_foo.DoSomething();`, without wrapping it in a `Task.Run`.

In case running the operation on a background thread is important, a Proxy or Decorator for `IFoo` can be created that wraps the call to the real `Foo` in a `Task.Run`. When this Proxy implements `IFoo` as well, it can be used as stand-in for `Foo`, without `App` having to know about this.

An example of this model can be found [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications) with the `AsyncMailSenderProxy`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Steven. If I for example want to delay the injection of Bar into Foo until Bar state is filled and initialized (which is middway through the app) how would I be able to achieve this? The decorator mechanism doesn't seem to work as Bar gets injected into Foo when I call container.GetInstance<App>(); which is too early. Thanks.